# how to convert sql to query builder laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Can anyone help me out to convert this SQL to query builder!

```
SELECT topwords.*, 
       mw.word AS my_word 
FROM   topwords 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT words.word 
                  FROM   definition_word 
                         JOIN words 
                           ON words.id = definition_word.word_id 
                  WHERE  definition_word.user_id = $user) AS mw 
              ON topwords.word = mw.word
```

I have a problem with how to use a subquery in leftjoin!

I tried something like this but it has error!
[See error as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4CCX.png)

```
DB::table('topwords')
                    ->leftJoin(DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT
                    words.word
                    FROM definition_word 
                    JOIN words ON words.id = definition_word.word_id
                    WHERE definition_word.user_id = $user as mw"),"topwords.word", "=", "mw.word" )
                    ->select(
                        "topwords.*",
                        "mw.word AS my_word"
                    )->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Join Sub query official document [subquery-joins](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-joins)

```
$mw = DB::table('words')
        ->select('DISTINCT words.word')
        ->join('definition_word', function($join) use ($user)
        {
            $join->on('wordss.id', '=', 'definition_word.word_id')
                 ->where('definition_word.user_id',  $user);
        });
        
$topwords = DB::table('topwords')
        ->joinSub($mw, 'mw',function ($join) {
            $join->on('topwords.word', '=', 'mw.word');
        })
        ->select('topwords.*','mw.word AS my_word')
        ->orderBy('id','desc')
        ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Hello! When I check dd($topwords) topwords variable there is not an array that will be displayed on the table.  https://prnt.sc/xpgn87 see an image of $topwords variable. If you can help me 
 thank you in advance !

Comment: the dd of topwards will return lengthAwarePaginator object the actual data will be in items that appear in your image as  empty array

Comment: But I have 4500 records in the table and as the standard SQL it was selecting records. if you can help, please... Thank you in advance

Comment: ok what about get $mw the dd it dd($mw->get()); before use join sub to show what exactly on first query result

Comment: also you can return $topwords in foreach loop in blade or just return reponse json to show it's item

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because of **paginate** and aggregation

Try to make custom pagination, using LengthAwarePaginator

Here is example: [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-use-lengthawarepaginator-manual-paginator)

So you need to make something like this:

```
  $query = DB::table('topwords')
                        ->leftJoin(DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT
                        words.word
                        FROM definition_word 
                        JOIN words ON words.id = definition_word.word_id
                        WHERE definition_word.user_id = $user as mw"),"topwords.word", "=", "mw.word" )
                        ->select(
                            "topwords.*",
                            "mw.word AS my_word"
                        );
    
    
    $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($query->get(), $query->count(), $request->input('per_page', 15), $request->input('page', 1));
```

And then you can use it in the collection

Comment: Hello! I used this code but I have some error. if you can please help me.

--
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DISTINCT words.word FROM definition_word JOIN wo' at line 1 (SQL: select `topwords`.*, `mw`.`word` as `my_word` from `topwords` left join SELECT DISTINCT words.word FROM definition_word JOIN words ON words.id = definition_word.word_id WHERE definition_word.user_id = 2 as mw on `topwords`.`word` = `mw`.`word`)

Comment: I think you need to put SELECT statement into braces
Like: "(SELECT DISTINCT ..... $user as mw) "